# What happened to my ext3 partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, dd

I had an ext3 partition. I ran a dd command like this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/part2 bs=1024 count=15000 seek="various values"
```

Where `various values` are basically 0, 15000K, 30000K etc.

The point is I ran the dd command on the entire partition.

Now the partition won't mount. I get an error "Can't find ext3 partition on ..."

Questions:

1. What exactly happened to the partition? I know it got corrupted, but what exactly happened? As a clue `fsck /dev/part2` gives "The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2 filesystem."
2. How do I format it back to ext3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overwrote and/or corrupted superblock(s), and likely other data, with the data from `/dev/urandom`. Superblocks are important; they contain filesystem metadata.

You can format it back to `ext3` by issuing `mkfs.ext3 /dev/part2`.

Comment: thanks, that worked. Appreciate it. So what I was trying to do is basically write data to filesystem at various offsets. I think I should not have written directly to the device file. Can you please check a question I have posted here at Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594073/how-to-write-a-file-at-various-offsets-to-a-filesystem-partition-with-dd-command/9594299#9594299

Comment: @abc - I agree with everything Perry said, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate about getting back the ext3 filesystem, you can run `e2fsck` with the `-b NUM` parameter, where NUM is the alternate superblock.  Read the man page for e2fsck to get that number.  Depending on the blocksize of the partition, you might have not overwritten it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend even trying this once data has been written directly to the device. More than likely even if it initially appears to work, all hell will break loose.

Comment: It'll be a data recovery mission at best, since a lot must have been overwritten. It won't become a usable filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing one could try in this situation is the program **gpart**.  It attempts to guess missing partition (and filesystem) information - so, it might be able to recover that partition well enough to pull data off of it.

As the comments to jsbillings answer suggest, do not rely on the partition after this; this is recovery - pull off your data and make a new partition.   (Other standard recovery tips/rules apply, too - like, "make an image, and work on that, not the original.")

(And yes, I realize this is too late to help the OP.  Might help others, though.)